# is there any method in pandas to convert dataframe from day to defaullt d/m/y format?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to convert all day in the data-frame into day/feb/2020 format
[here date field consist only day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4TNp.png)

[from first one convert the date field like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dahcw.png)

My current approach is:

```
import datetime

y=[]
for day in planned_ds.Date:
    x=datetime.datetime(2020, 5, day)

    print(x)
```

Is there any easy method to convert all day data-frame to d/m/y format?

Comment: Hi @Kiran and welcome! May I suggest you copy your code in the post, rather than linking images? Not everyone will be able to see them. Additionally, you shouldn't rely on `print()` for a specific format. Try use the `strftime` method of the `datetime` object, for instance: `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way as assuming you have data like

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5], columns=["date"])
```

is to convert them to dates and then shift them to start when you need them to:

```
pd.to_datetime(df["date"], unit="D") - pd.datetime(1970,1,1) + pd.datetime(2020,1,31)
```

this results in

```
0   2020-02-01
1   2020-02-02
2   2020-02-03
3   2020-02-04
4   2020-02-05
```

Comment: i want to get all day into default 2020-2-day format ,here i also get 2020-03-day

Comment: What value gave you 2020-03-day? I assume it was larger than 29? In such a case, what would you want it to do? You need to include sample inputs, your image only has integers from 1 - 9.

Comment: yes my data is large (3024 rows),but every value is less than 30,i used melt function .

Comment: If every value is less than 30 then how could get _2020-03-day_ ?